# MySQL - Conditional Join for a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization

I have the following query:

```
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as Visits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address

group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

and I also have this one:

```
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit /* Another join has been added */

group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

As you can see the queries are almost the same one except for an extra `join` statement.
Both queries return me the correct values I need, but I need to join them in a single table, so I do this:

```
select fffuuu.ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as Visitas, fffuuu.doneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address

join (
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as doneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit

group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
) as fffuuu on sf_address.ad_st_id_state = fffuuu.ad_st_id_state

group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

Or in other words, I join the first query with the second one as a subquery. The resultset is fine and correct but is taking too long, so I got a timeout in another system this query is being run. Each query independently runs fast, but joining them is too slow for my needs...

I'd like to know if there is a way to optimize this, I was thinking if there is some join conditional statement or something. I searched for info but I didn't have any luck. I was thinking in something like:

```
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as Visits, if(@someVariable := true) as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
if (@someVariable == true) then join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit

group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

Or something like that. How can I optimize this?

Comment: The following works in t-sql so im sure it will work in mysql too add a join something like.... JOIN sf_visit_file_time on id_visis = vft_vi_id_visit and @someVariable = 1

Comment: @SkelDave I tried your suggestion but I'm not sure how to do it, because I got a syntaxis error in MySQL. I just made up that code about the someVariable to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use an outer join to sf_visit_file_time and a case statement in your count? Obviously I don't have your schema locally but something like:

```
select ad_st_id_state, 
   count(distinct id_visit) as Visits,
   count(distinct case when vft_vi_id_visit is not null then id_visit end) as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
left join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit
group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

Comment: Right enough Gordon. In my example the first count gets visits that are not done rather than all visits. In the second, I added the 0 as I was worried about adding null to a count in mysql, I don't have an instance handy to check what that does. I assume from your response, it adds a 0?

Comment: Hey you both did it! This answer works too and it's shorter and clearer! I'd like to give proper read to every answer fisrt before chosing the best one, but I really like this one. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: @Metafaniel A word of caution, a left join can definitely be slower than a regular join depending on the size of the tables, though this answer definitely is cleaner.

Comment: @SLin Thanks for the warning, I'm not a join expert, so I'll try to remember your advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If both queries are fast and work nicely and you just need the results in one table, you can use a union select http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as Visits, '' as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
group by ad_st_id_state
UNION
select ad_st_id_state, '' as Visits, count(distinct id_visit) as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit /* Another join has been added */
group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

Comment: I tried but I got an `Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY` Probably I just don't know much about `union` =P I rarely use it. Can you please explain me further? I just enclose each query between parenthesis and added `union` =P

Comment: @Metafaniel added a sample for you. I assume you want to distinguish between Visits and DoneVisists.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be useful, I understood `union` better with this example, HOWEVER instead of numbers, I got a `BLOB` sign in my resultset. Any ideas why? THANKS AGAIN

Comment: @Metafaniel You got a BLOB sign as the resultset? That is strange, I don't have your tables so I can't comment on that. try maybe putting a default value of 0 instead of the '' that are in the query in the query. What are you using to run the mysql query?

Comment: I followed your advice replacing `''` with `0` and the blob sign has gone =P I'm working with `MySQL Workbench 6.1 at te moment`

Comment: Your answer ALMOST works, but there is a problem: I got two rows instead of just one. Both have the `ad_st_id_state` value and one row has the Visits value and the other row the DoneVisits value. If your answer could join these 2 rows into one, it will be great. Thanks again

Comment: Ahh, if you want to have the two results joined by ad_st_id_state then Ollie's answer definitely works better. Union is only for combining result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Both your queries are clean and efficient. So, simply join them together for presentation, treating each of them as a subquery.

```
SELECT a.ad_st_id_state, a.Visits, b.DoneVisits
  FROM (
        /* put your first query here */
       ) AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
        /* put your second query here */
       ) AS b ON a.ad_st_id_state = b.ad_st_id_state
 ORDER BY a.ad_st_id_state
```

This makes for a bigger query, but it should run in the sum of the time of the two queries you have.  You can leave the `ORDER BY` clauses out of your subqueries.

So it looks like this ... a veritable club sandwich of a query.

```
SELECT a.ad_st_id_state, a.Visits, b.DoneVisits
  FROM (
          select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as Visits
            from sf_visit
            join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
            join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
            join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
           group by ad_st_id_state
       ) AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
           select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct id_visit) as DoneVisits
            from sf_visit
            join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
            join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
            join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
            join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit /* Another join */
           group by ad_st_id_state
       ) AS b ON a.ad_st_id_state = b.ad_st_id_state
 ORDER BY a.ad_st_id_state
```

Comment: I've managed to follow your answer and I've got the desired result! And yup is much much faster than I was trying to do. You were right, I just needed a sanwich hehe. I'm trying to figure out the others answers first but probably this one will be the answer. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're "conditional join" is telling you "if I find a record in this other table, it means that the visit is done."

In order to create that "condition" you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

An `OUTER JOIN` as opposed to an `INNER JOIN` doesn't break if records are found in one table and not the other. It still returns records. There are `LEFT` and `RIGHT` outer joins. You should research them yourself. But basically, to achieve what you want, you could do something like this:

```
select ad_st_id_state, count(distinct vft_vi_id_visit) as DoneVisits
from sf_visit
join vr_users on vi_us_id_user = sus_us_id_user
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_address on pdv_ad_id_address = id_address
left outer join sf_visit_file_time on id_visit = vft_vi_id_visit /* Another join has been added */
group by ad_st_id_state
order by ad_st_id_state
```

So now, DoneVisits will always be there -- it will just be zero when there are no `sf_visit_file_time` records for it.

Comment: I understand your point but in this case the ´left outer join´ returns me the Visits value and an `inner join` returns me the DoneVisits value, but I needed both in a single result set. Thanks for your answer

Comment: That's what this was meant to do. I see now that `id_visit` is the wrong column to count DISTINCT. It should have been `vft_vi_id_visit`. I updated my answer accordingly. The concept described is what you need, though, as is evident by the answer you accepted.